# What happens if malloc((size_t)NULL) in C

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

What happen I write `malloc((size_t)NULL)` for dynamic memory allocation in C?

```
int main()
{
    char *ptr = malloc((size_t)NULL);
}
```

**Is it allocate memory in heap section?** or **Is it undefined behavior?**

Comment: It's just like malloc(0).

Comment: Once you deal with the compiler warnings, you won't be running code like that.

Comment: This won't compile since malloc arguement needs to be numerical value.  NULL is not a numerical value.  char *ptr = malloc(sizeof(NULL)); allocates 8 bytes of memory.

Comment: @Nguaial it could be a numerical value

Comment: @M.M I get "warning C4047: 'function': 'size_t' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'" and also "warning C4024: 'malloc': different types for formal and actual parameter 1" after adding `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour due to calling function returning `void*` without a prototype in scope

Comment: I am running linux in C9.  This code allocated 8 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

> *What happen I write `malloc(NULL)`..*

Wait, ***stop***, you do not write `malloc(NULL)`, why would you?

The argument to `malloc()` is the "size" of the memory expected, that is **not** supposed to be a null pointer constant.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.4, (*emphasis mine*)

> ```
> void *malloc(size_t size);
> ```
>
> The `malloc` function allocates **space for an object whose size is specified by `size`** and
>   whose value is indeterminate.

That said, for most cases, `NULL` is represented by integer constant value `0`, so `malloc(NULL)` is equivalent to `malloc(0)`, which again is implementation defined behavior.

Quoting chapter §7.22.3./P1

> [...] If the size of
>   the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation-defined: either a null pointer
>   is returned, or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the
>   returned pointer shall not be used to access an object.

Comment: @M.M nopes, its implementation defined, kindly see the edit above. :)

Answer (score 0):

This allocates the amount of memory defined by the constant `NULL`. If `NULL == 0`, then behavior is [implementation defined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html).

Comment: `NULL == 0` is always true

Comment: There is no indication in the posted code about the value of NULL.